# How to free double pointer struct in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I got a struct that defined like this :

```
typedef struct {
char userType;                          // - The type of the user.
char userName[userName_len];            // - The user's user name.
char password[password_len];            // - The user's password.
char id[id_len];                        // - The user's id.
char firstName[userName_len];           // - The users first name.
char lastName[userName_len];            // - The user's surname.
char address[address_len];              // - The user's address.
}Users;
```

and a pointer for that struct in the main function (not global pointer):

```
Users* users_db = NULL;
```

I fill that data base from a text file and sending the pointer to it like this :

```
Fill_Databases(&users_db,&qnty); //qnty is a pointer to Quantity struct used for help.
```

Fill_Databases transfers the pointer to other function like this :

```
Fill_Users_db(users_db, &*qnty);
```

In that function there is memory allocation using calloc .

Now I need to free the stucts and I'm getting a running time problem "has triggered a breakpoint."

I send it to Free_Databases function the same way as I allocate memory for em and trying to free em like this :

```
 void Free_Users_db(Users** users_db, Quantity qnty)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < qnty.Users; i++)
    {
        free(users_db[i]);
        users_db[i] = NULL;
    }
    free(users_db);
    users_db = NULL;
    puts("users db free");
}
```

Whats wrong with that? And what the right way to free em ?

edit:
Allocation added:

```
    void Fill_Users_db(Users** users_db, Quantity* qnty)
{
    //fills the employee database array according to the file
    int num_of_users = 0, i;
    FILE *file = fopen("Users.txt", "r"); //open the file
    if (!file) //if failed to open file
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        return;
    }
    fscanf(file, "%d", &qnty->Users);
    *users_db = (Users*)calloc(qnty->Users, sizeof(Users)); //allocate memory and nullify elements //used calloc coz it takes 2 arguments and not 1 as calloc.
    if (!*users_db)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed!\n");
        return;
    }
    //for each user get data from the file and allocate memory to the relevant struct variables
    for (i = 0; !feof(file); i++)
    {
        fscanf(file, "%s" "%s" "%s" "%s" "%s" "%s", &(*users_db)[i].userType, &(*users_db)[i].userName, &(*users_db)[i].password, &(*users_db)[i].id, &(*users_db)[i].firstName, &(*users_db)[i].lastName);
        fgetline(&(*users_db)[i].address, file);
    }

    fclose(file); //close the file
}
```

Comment: Can you add more code about the way you allocate memory for users_db?

Comment: Note, `feof` is actually incorrect as a loop sentinel since you need to read past `EOF`.

Comment: @Jason Ok thank you thank to you I read this article now I get it:http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1046476070&id=1043284351

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`users_db` is defined in the main function as an array of `Users` structs, not an array of pointers. Therefore it's an error to `free()` the individual array elements. Also, you need to dereference the users_db pointer, since you're passing it as a double pointer. Try the following.

```
void Free_Users_db(Users** users_db, Quantity qnty)
{
    free(*users_db);
    *users_db = NULL;
    puts("users db free");
}
```

Comment: I already tried it like this and it works , but what about the other elements of Users array , shouldn't I free em also ? This one frees only the pointer it self ? I understand that I should free all of the array elements?

Comment: All the elements of the array are allocated at once, with a single call to `calloc()`. Notice the size of the block is the number of array elements multiplied by the size of each element. It's all one block of memory, so it must all be freed at once. You can't pass arbitrary pointers to `free()`, you must pass a pointer that was returned from one of the `malloc()` family of functions.

Comment: If you had implemented `users_db` as an array of pointers, you could then have called `calloc()` once for each element of the array. In that situation, you would need to call `free()` once for each element when you were done. But in your code, it's all done with a single call to `calloc()`, so you just call `free()` once. You need to match each call to a memory allocation function with a corresponding call to `free()`.

Comment: Just to be clear, `free(*users_db)` frees the entire array that was allocated with `calloc()`, not just the first element.

Comment: Ok got it ! Thanks for full explanation :) It was one of the times where I though it was to easy to free it like this. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Btw, do you have any suggestions how to check if the memory got completely freed ? I did a debugging on *users_db it seems to be nullified , but how can I check if it is "really" freed?

Comment: C itself doesn't have a way do that; you would need to use a debugging tool that checks for memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

```
void Free_Users_db(Users** users_db, Quantity qnty)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < qnty.Users; i++)
    {
        free(users_db[i]);
        users_db[i] = NULL;
    }
    free(users_db);
    users_db = NULL;
    puts("users db free");
}
```

should be

```
  void Free_Users_db(Users** users_db, Quantity qnty)
    {
        int i;
       /* for (i = 0; i < qnty.Users; i++)
        {
            free(users_db[i]);
            users_db[i] = NULL;
        }*/
        free(*users_db);
        *users_db = NULL;
        puts("users db free");
    }
```

As you can see in the `Fill_Users_db` function, there is only one call to `calloc`. Why do you map one call to an allocation function to multiple calls to `free`? It is incorrect. Each call to an allocation function like `malloc` or `calloc` should be mapped to just one call to `free`.

Comment: Thank you 2 for explanation :) Got it now!